# Roles.RoleExists() causes SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 Internet application with the account controller.

I'm trying to add roles and give the user the option of choosing between 3 roles on singup, my register method looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!Roles.RoleExists("user"))
            {
                Roles.CreateRole("user");
            }

            if (!Roles.RoleExists("superuser"))
            {
                Roles.CreateRole("superuser");
            }

            if (!Roles.RoleExists("admin"))
            {
                Roles.CreateRole("admin");
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {


                var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName);

                string userType = null;
                switch (model.Type)
                {
                    case 1:
                        userType = "user";                         
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        userType = "superuser";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        userType = "admin";
                        break;
                    default:
                        return View(model);
                        break;
                }


                var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id,userType);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

When I try to sign up and the code reaches  `if (!Roles.RoleExists("user"))` the sites hangs a about 10 seconds and I get the following error:

```
SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 


    [SqlException (0x80131904): Der opstod en netværksrelateret eller forekomstspecifik fejl, da det blev forsøgt at oprette forbindelse til SQL Server. Serveren blev ikke fundet, eller der var ikke adgang til den. Kontroller, at forekomstnavnet er korrekt, og at SQL Server er konfigureret til at tillade fjernforbindelser. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Fejl ved søgning efter angivet server/forekomst.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340655
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5350915
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +922
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5353725
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +5355926
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +75

[HttpException (0x80004005): Der kan ikke oprettes forbindelse til SQL Server-databasen.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +130
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +89
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +27
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +386
```

I don't know how to change the error messages to english.

in web.config I added `<roleManager enabled="true" />` to system.web and my connectionstring looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=lmjzf199gd.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=lenioDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lenio;Password=*******;Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Obviously password is not set to "*******" in the connection string.

I use a database which is on azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `<roleManager enabled="true">` you have to specify your role provider together with the correct connectionstring (this is the issue). Example:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

But first make sure that your database has already all the tables and sql procedures required for the default provider to work by installing aspnet_regsql ([see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx)).

Comment: When I change it I now get this error: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'. When I try to signup.

Comment: Your answer fixed my initial problem but cause a new. I will post another question on that later.